# Why is window.event not working?

Tags: javascript

It used to work but now I get a:

```
window.event is undefined
```

From this simple code that used to work:

```
function checkKey() {   
    if (window.event.keyCode != 9) {    
        document.actionForm.saveStatus.value = "Not saved";
    }
}
```

Why can't I use window.event anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`window.event` is a proprietary Microsoftism.

The standard way to access data about an event is via the first argument of the event handler function.

Comment: I only need Internet Explorer compatibility. Can I use it then if I only care about IE 7+?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if Microsoft deprecated the old-style `event` object, so I wouldn't bet on it (outside of compatibility mode anyway)

Comment: Chrome also supports `window.event`. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

```
function checkKey(e) {
  var evt = e || window.event,
      keyPressed = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
  if (keyPressed  != 9) {    
    document.actionForm.saveStatus.value = "Not saved";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can standardize the check like so:

```
function checkKey(e) {
    var evt = e || window.event;
    if (evt.keyCode != 9) {    
        document.actionForm.saveStatus.value = "Not saved";
    }
}
```