# should not accept digits in text field

Tags: javascript

I'm working with a text field that should NOT accept digits in it. So I have written a script with function named validate(). Even though it looks working, it is very bad. The user is able to see the data (i mean, the unwanted digits) entered. I want to check the user input before displaying it. If the user entered data is not a digit, then only it should be visible. Is there a function like **getch() of C-language** in javascript (or) suggest me a solution for this?

Here is my code:

```
    <script>
    function validate()
    {
      var s=t1.value;
      var res="";
      for(i=0;i<s.length;i++)
      {
        var ascii=s.charCodeAt(i);
        if(ascii<48 || ascii>57)
          res+=String.fromCharCode(ascii);  
      }
      t1.value=res;
    }
    </script>
    <input type="text" id="t1" onkeypress="val();">
```

Comment: Your `onkeypress` event is trying to call the method `val`, while your JS defines the function `validate`. These two things have to match.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508183/how-to-force-input-to-only-allow-alpha-letters

Answer (score 4):

```
onkeypress="val()";
```

whereas you have written a method called `validate()`

so change it to

```
onkeypress="validate()";
```

Remaining seems good, see [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XPvU2/)

Answer (score 3):

Call this function on key press from your html element | **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RtUcz/)**

Number wil not be accepted and **will not be visible in text box**

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return checks(this,event)" />
```

JavaScript

```
function checks(dis,ev)
{
 var e = ev || window.event;
 var key = e.which||e.keyCode;
if(key>=48 && key<=57)
return false;
else
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
<script>
  function validate(input){
     return (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57);
  }
</script>
<input type="text" id="t1" onkeydown="return validate(this);">
```

Running here: http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/XPvU2/1/

Hope this helps. Cheers