# How do I allow the user to only input a string?

Tags: javascript, html, string, validation, alphabetical

```
function EnterCandidates() {
  var candidateNameInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[id^=C]'),
    names = document.querySelectorAll('label[for^=V][id^=L_V]');

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(names, function(label, index) {
    if (candidateNameInputs[index].value !== candidateNameInputs[index].defaultValue) {
      label.textContent = candidateNameInputs[index].value;
    }
  });
}
```

I have this code which gets the users input and changes the label with it but i want to add some code which only allows the user to enter letters of the alphabet. How would I go about this using this code?

Comment: Get an ascii range for all letters you want and prevent the default behavior when a key pressed the value is not in this range(using javascript).

Comment: Let them input anything, and then show them what they're actually sending: http://jsfiddle.net/g1Lbh905/

Comment: @erohs2000 i have answered this in you previous question as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using modern browsers then user html5 validation -

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="field" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" />
```

It accepts `a-z` and `A-Z` plus space

Comment: I don't think it works because it does not show that it is red.

Comment: you didn't mention the 'red' part anywhere

Answer (score 0):

listen to keyDown event and match with this regex:

```
/[a-zA-Z]+/
```

if you're targeting modern browsers only, you can try this:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z]" title="Only letters" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var val = document.getElementById('id').value;

if (!val.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) 
{
alert('Only alphabets are allowed');
return false;
}
```

full script

```
function EnterCandidates() {
console.log('woo');
var candidateNameInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[id^=C]'),
    names = document.querySelectorAll('label[for^=V][id^=L_V]');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(names, function (label, index) {
    if (!candidateNameInputs[index].value.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) 
     {
         alert('Only alphabets are allowed');
    }
    else
    {
         if (candidateNameInputs[index].value !==  candidateNameInputs[index].defaultValue) {
        label.textContent = candidateNameInputs[index].value;
    }
    }

});
}
```

Comment: @mail-nv not really, especially for this use case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940137/regex-test-v-s-string-match-to-know-if-a-string-matches-a-regular-expression - this is the speed of match vs test and IT MATTERS, even in this case!
And see here: http://jsperf.com/regexp-vs-indexof

Comment: yes there will be a difference if you user is going to be typing 600,000 times per minute. Then the user will some performance degradation.

Comment: As Muhammad Umer said in this case its micro performance issue.

Comment: @Iceburg It seems to be in a loop. How do I make it so it only displays it once without having to click ok a couple of times?

Answer (score 0):

you can't avoid that the user types non alphabetic characters. But you can:
- control the input fields (onkeydown) and check if there are some characters you don't want [Stackoverflow - force input to only alpha-letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508183/how-to-force-input-to-only-allow-alpha-letters)
- do the same before the 
label.textContent = candidateNameInputs[index].value;
line and filter/replace the characters you don't want

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it using Javascript.

http://jsfiddle.net/q60gm0ra/

```
var input = document.getElementById('alpha');

input.addEventListener('keypress',function(e) { 
    var str = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);
    if (!(/[A-Z]|\s/i).test(str)) {
       e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you do the same thing for numbers?

Comment: sure. just remove the `!` symbol

Comment: Inputs can change in other ways than pressing keys in a keyboard, e.g. using the mouse to paste text.

Comment: good point, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226574/disable-copy-paste-into-html-form-using-javascript/26255397#26255397